# error with opening Aptana studio on fedora

Tags: aptana, fedora

I,ve just installed Aptana Studio 3 on Fedora23 and I tried to run and i got this:

```
    # AptanaStudio3
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
No protocol specified
Aptana Studio 3: Cannot open display: 
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Aptana Studio 3: Cannot open display: 
Aptana Studio 3:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/usr/local/bin/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/1447674547664.log.
```

And the log file(1447674547664.log) here if it helps:

```
    !
```

> ### SESSION 2015-11-16 15:19:07.286
>
> ```
> eclipse.buildId=unknown
> java.version=1.8.0_65
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
> BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
> Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-11-16 15:19:09.950
> !MESSAGE Application error
> !STACK 1
> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
>   at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:925)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:909)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
>   at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:162)
>   at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:94)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
> ```

Any suggestion?

Comment: List 1447674547664.log here.

Comment: @usualdeveloper Log file added.